# Memory increase when using qt spline chart

Tags: qt, c++11, charts, qt5

I have used qt spline chart . The chart add a point dynamicly every one second . 
The problem that when i use a QPushButton to remove all points from series except the five newest one , the memory still increase .

Comment: After investigation , it appears that is caused by QXYSeries:: remove (...). This fuction remove only the point from the graph and did not free the memory.
see  : 
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58802

Comment: This bug was fixed in QT5.9